# Security protected for my video and pdf files?

Tags: android, file

I am working on an app which downloads videos and pdf files from server .As these all files are very important I dont want these files to be copied or edited.So I need to know any perfect method to protect my files on sdcard or internal storage memory.I have tried using the data/data/package-name folder but this is not solving my problem .

Something like a folder with key which could be used only by my app using a key.
Someone who had similar problem please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**"I have tried using the data/data/package-name folder but this is not solving my problem ."**

- If your device is routed then anyone can access these files from `data/data/<package_name>/` directory.

The only ways is you have to use some **Encryption - Decryption** (some lengthy way ) for those files..

Comment: Please see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6676574/securing-media-files-in-the-mobile 
This could be used for videos and pdf files.?

Comment: Yes, I already knew about it, That's why I mentioned Encryption-Decryption for files in my answer..

Comment: I think this method is perfect for the videos But doubtful for pdf.
Any ways thanx for the answer.