# How to protect confidential data in android application

Tags: android, performance, security

I am using confidential data(like URL's, secret code etc) in my android application.

I want to protect my confidential data to access from the outside world (some thing like decompiling my class files etc.)

Please let me know what I need to do so that It can not be hacked by hackers.

Thanks.

Comment: you can store this data inside app at the encrypted state. Then add encryption\decryption method, which you will call each time you will need to decrypt data, and once the app will be process via proguard, it will be hard challenge to restore data via decompiling, I guess. There is no 100% security.

Answer (score 1):

Content generated by an app that is deployed on a user's device cannot be 100% secure, but you can make attacker's life difficult. The idea is to make it difficult enough for cracking not to be worthwhile.

- [This article](http://android-developers.blogspot.fr/2013/02/using-cryptography-to-store-credentials.html) (and linked related articles) is about using cryptography. This is a good way to get started in securing generated or exchanged contents.
- [This article](http://android-developers.blogspot.fr/2010/09/proguard-android-and-licensing-server.html) (and linked related articles, too) is about obfuscating your application code. The purpose of obfuscation is to make the reverse-engineering of your app more difficult once decompiled.
- And [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6676574/securing-media-files-in-the-mobile/6676826#6676826) can also be helpful to get started **but** the proposed implementation has an issue and needs revisiting (It works but has a hole. I've put an EDIT note in the post itself to explain that further).

Answer (score 1):

By using encryption and decryption you can protect your data. This is - [sample example](http://iamvijayakumar.blogspot.in/2013/10/android-example-for-encrypt-and-decrypt.html)

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible. If it is inside the app, it is vulnerable to attackers.

Comment: but there are ways to make life harder for decompilers

Comment: Harder does not answer the question. The question is how to protect it, not how to minorly inconvenience an attacker